# How to make Conditional Probability Tables (CPTs) for Bayesian networks with pymc

Tags: python, bayesian-networks, pymc, dirichlet, discrete-space

I would like to build a Bayesian network of discrete (pymc.Categorical) variables that are dependent on other categorical variables.
As a [simplest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shpigi/pieces/master/ab.png) example, suppose variables *a* and *b* are categorical and *b* depends on *a*

Here is an attempt to code it with pymc (assuming *a* takes one of three values and *b* takes one of four values). The idea being that the CPT distributions would be learned from data using pymc.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
aRange = 3
bRange = 4

#make variable a
a = pm.Categorical('a',pm.Dirichlet('aCPT',np.ones(aRange)/aRange))

#make a CPT table as an array of 
CPTLines = np.empty(aRange, dtype=object)
for i in range(aRange):
    CPTLines[i] = pm.Dirichlet('CPTLine%i' %i,np.ones(bRange)/bRange)

#make a deterministic node that holds the relevant CPT line (dependent on state1)
@pm.deterministic
def selectedCPTLine(CPTLines=CPTLines,a=a):
    return CPTLines[a]

#make a node for variable b 
b=pm.Categorical('b', selectedCPTLine)

model = pm.MCMC([a, b, selectedCPTLine])
```

If we draw this model it looks like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shpigi/pieces/master/abD.png)

However, running this code we get an error:

```
Probabilities in categorical_like sum to [ 0.8603345]
```

Apparently, pymc can take a Dirichlet variable as the parameter of a Categorical variable. 
When the Categorical variable gets a Dirichlet variable as its parameter, it knows to expect a k-1 vector of probabilities with the assumption that the kth probability sums the vector to 1. This breaks down, however, when the Dirichlet variable is the output of a deterministic variable, which is what I need to make a CPT.

Am I going about this the right way? How can the representation mismatch be solved? I should mention that I'm relatively new to pymc and Python.

This question is related to a previous question on [making a discrete state Markov model with pymc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636974/making-a-discrete-state-markov-model-with-pymc)

Comment: I also tried replacing the deterministic variable definition for selectedCPTLine with a pymc.Index but this does not solve the Dirichlet - Categorical incompatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, thanks. The problem is that, while usually, PyMC will recognize a Dirichlet as the parent of a Categorical and completes the probability simplex, here your Categoricals are embedded in a Container, and the Categorical does not make the automatic adjustment needed. The following code does this for you:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
aRange = 3
bRange = 4

aCPT = pm.Dirichlet('aCPT', np.ones(aRange))

#make variable a
a = pm.Categorical('a', aCPT)

#make a CPT table as an array of
CPTLines = [pm.Dirichlet('CPTLine%i' %i, np.ones(bRange)) for i in range(aRange)]

#make a node for variable b
@pm.stochastic(dtype=int)
def b(value=0, CPT=CPTLines, a=a):
    return pm.categorical_like(value, p=pm.extend_dirichlet(CPT[a]))

model = pm.MCMC([a, b, CPTLines])
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like this is what I needed!
Any ideas why the definition of b returns:  

"ZeroProbability: Stochastic b's value is outside its support,
 or it forbids its parents' current values." ?

Comment: Means that there were invalid values, such as integers outside the range of the categorical variable.

Comment: right. was missing dtype=int. This now works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A couple points of confusion:

- your model seems to contain no data (observed stochastics), so there is no information to fit the model
- not sure what you mean by a Dirichlet variable being the output of a deterministic. As long as the probabilities are of length k-1 and they sum to less than one, you should be good. If you have a value that sums to unity, you can just pass the first k-1 of the values.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  
* My model contains no data because I put together something simple as an example. In a real-world problem, there would be more variables and some would have observed data that would drive the distributions of the rest.

Comment: Regarding your second point:  I have a deterministic function (selectCPTLine) that takes an array of Dirichlet variables and a categorical variable that serves to select which Dirichlet variable is the function's output. So the function returns a Dirichlet variable. I guess I should have written    "deterministic function", not "variable".  
Hope this clarifies what I'm trying to do.